# loading facebook share on page load

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I am trying to initiate a facebook share by simply clicking a link in an e-mail. I want the link to lead to the site, but also automate a share on social media(FB is easiest to work with but ideally it would be shared on any social media currently available when the e-mail recipient clicks the link).

I wanted to assign the share function and the link to a single button put into an e-mail in HTML but multiple searches said that's not really possible. The most promising method seemed to be onpageload or onload to run a .js for sharer.  I'm not a coder, just learning as I need it.  I put together the two basic elements needed to have the page load, but it seems to do nothing.

I've looked, and I'm sure the answer is simple, already somewhere, but I'm asking the wrong question.

Here's the code with a simple template around it.

```
  </head>

   <body onload="share()">

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script>
    FB.ui(
     {
       method: 'share',
       href: 'https://www.postprep.com',
      },
     // callback
     function(response) {
     if (response && !response.error_message) {
     alert('Posting completed.');
      } else {
      alert('Error while posting.');
      }
      } 
      );
      </script>

      </body>
      </html>
```

I'm just kind of piecing it together, but I'm either needing to put the .js in the scriptsrc tag or some syntax error won't allow me to load the page...help is appreciated,

Comment: Most e-mail clients and mail web interfaces do not execute any JavaScript embedded into e-mails.